# Laplace transform: time scaling of the unit step function

Tags: laplace-transform, step-function

EDIT: It gets the same answer.

I have read that the time scaling property of the Laplace transform is not relevant for the unit step function.
This property being:
$$\mathcal L \left[f(at)\right]= \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)F\left(\frac{s}{a}\right)$$
Does this mean that: $$\mathcal L \left[5u\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right]= \left(\frac{5}{s}\right)$$
Or does it still hold and the transform is then:
$$\mathcal L \left[5u\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right]= 5\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)}\right)=\left(\frac{10}{1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2s}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{s}\right)$$

Comment: This is good to ask but I'm not sure what did you mean by a unit step function $u(\frac t{2})$
How would you show this in graph? An unit step function is like a shifted function 
$$u(t-a) = 1 \text{ if: } t>a \text{ else: } 0$$

Comment: Potentially the answer is just $$\frac{5}{s}$$ Because for any $t>0$, the step function is 1. But I'm not sure.